# Call to undefined function protect()

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP function in my site to help eliminate SQL Injection.

I don't know if I have done this right, and I've tried to Google my question however it seems to be only wordpress related. I have my function in a file named `requirements.php` and have used `require("requirements.php");` in order to call the file.

However when it's called in the html there is the error

> Call to undefined function protect()

Here is the PHP script where the file is called:

```
<?php
require("database.php");
require("requirements.php");
$email = protect($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = protect($con, $_POST['password']);
$confpassword = protect($con, $_POST['confpassword']);

(The file continutes...)
```

And here is the file "requirements.php"

```
<?php
    session_start();


     function protect ($con, $str){
        $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $str);
        return $str;
    }
?>
```

The error occurs on line 4 reading:

```
$email = protect($con, $_POST['email']);
```

(Where `protect` is called)

I had someone working on my project who did this, however they aren't around to ask about this therefore I figured after some trial and error I would ask here.

Comment: Did you open php in your requirements.php file? If you copied it directly, it looks like it's missing.

Comment: You should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: exactly as @the_pete said. no `<?php` tag, no php code. it'll be treated as plaintext output, NOT executable code.

Comment: There is a <?php tag, I didn't put it - I'll edit now

Comment: it's ok that you want to learn but why overburdening your self. why second file needed, and why that extra function code.?